# onCreateView() Requires API level 11.. how to support Activities on older devices (Android Activity)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-support-library, android-version

So far I've only bothered supporting Android API 11 and above, but this app is super simple, so I thought I'd try supporting down to 8. Eclipse only has *one* complaint, and that's my onCreateView method.  How do I handle this without raising my minSDK version?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context,
        AttributeSet attrs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);  //complains here
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call requires API level 11(current min is 8) android.app.Activity#onCreateView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181705/call-requires-api-level-11current-min-is-8-android-app-activityoncreateview)

Comment: I think your problem belongs to a bug, because there are 3 other SO-Threads with the same problem. Bug-Report is already open: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188677

Answer (score 1):

Override [the three-parameter version of `onCreateView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateView%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet%29) instead, dropping `View parent`.

Comment: I thought about that. So that wouldn't break support for newer Android versions?

Comment: @NSouth: Looking at the `Activity` and `LayoutInflater` source code, you might need to override both. The only time I see both being invoked on the same device would be for a `<fragment>` tag, where the four-parameter version chains to the three-parameter version for some reason. To be honest, in ~6 years of Android development, I have never had the need to override this method.