# Call requires API level 11(current min is 8) android.app.Activity#onCreateView

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie to android, and I am developing an android application. But my package line gives this error in MainActivity.java class.
Could anyone please tell me the reason of this?.
This is my class and the package line gives this error.

```
package com.example.eventgyaam;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

int counter;

Button add,sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is "+counter);
        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is "+counter);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Activity implementation as well as the build.gradle file for your module?

Comment: This is an Android SDK bug. I recommend starring it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188677) to help the developers know how many people are affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, some introductory details. There are *levels* of Android API and, at each level, they may introduce new functionality , as per [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels).

When you create an Android application, you specify the minimum level that your application will run on. This is done in the `manifest` with the `uses-sdk` stanza: see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) for details.

So, if you use functionality that's only available at level 11, your code *won't* run on a level 8 API like you've specified.

You either have to use only what's available at your current minimum, or up the minimum.

As to why you appear to be getting the error on the package line, and for a call that doesn't seem to be in the source code you've shown us, I couldn't say. Since it's complaining about `android.app.Activity#onCreateView` as per your title, there *may* be an issue with the view `R.layout.activity_main` that's being inflated by `setContentView`. Or it may be an issue with the compatibility library itself, [something that's not unheard of](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188677).

However, rather than struggling *too* hard with this, you may want to consider simply upping the minimum to API-11 and dropping the `appcompat` stuff altogether. As per [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Android_historical_version_distribution_-_vector.svg), only about 2% of Android users are still back on releases earlier than Android-3.0/API-11 (as of June 2016). That's only likely to get smaller as time goes by.

Comment: This answer is wrong, it seems you haven't read the question. In his code there is no functionality that he uses from api level 11. After sdk update I am getting same error, it seems there is a bug with their new sdk.

Comment: @user65721, there is also no oncreateview in the code either, which is what the error message is complaining about. I made no statement about the code given, only about how the API levels worked. If you can point to a *specific* statement of mine which is wrong (rather than a mis-reading of the answer), I'd be happy to fix it.

Comment: @ paxdiablo sorry for my poor wording, what I meant is, your post does not answer the question, your statements are correct and also helpful however it is not the correct answer for this question.

Comment: @user65721 that isn't true you can see my answer below.

Comment: For those who care, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically provides a way of writing legacy code for older APIs where necessary, while still providing the shiny new features.

Answer (score 6):

For each Android API, there might be new features added, which can't work on lower API versions. Thus, to fix this, you can just increase the minimum required API in your project.

In your `build.gradle (app-module)`, you will find this line:

```
minSdkVersion 8
```

Change it to:

```
minSdkVersion 11
```

If you didn't find this line in `build.gradle`, check your `AndroidManifest.xml` and change the `minSdkVersion` from 8 to 11 or whatever you want:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11" />
```

But now your app will only work on API 11+, which is fine. Nobody uses below API 11 these days, so it shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: Well, 5% are still using pre-3.0 but that's close enough to zero (and likely to get smaller as people upgrade their phones) in terms of a marketing decision :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo in my country, people using pre-3.0 are about 30% of the Android users (API level 10)

Comment: Epic, that may be so but mobile developers rarely target a single country, they're more interested in the worldwide market, especially at $0.99 a pop :-)

Answer (score 5):

**Error:**

> Call requires API level 11(current min is 8)
>   android.app.Activity#onCreateView

If you take a look at the javadoc for the Activity class you'll see that the method `public View onCreateView (View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` was added in API 11 that is why you are getting this error.

Either You have to Change your `minSdkVersion` from `8` to `11`

Or you Use `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` at the class declaration level as workaround for `Activity` like this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

For `Fragment`:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
```

`@SuppressLint("NewApi")` is an annotation used by the Android Lint tool.

Lint will tell you whenever something in your code isn't optimal or may crash. By passing NewApi there, you're suppressing all warnings that would tell you if you're using any API introduced after your `minSdkVersion`

EDIT:

You can also use `@TargetApi(11)` instead of `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`. More difference between these can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341042/what-is-better-suppresslint-or-targetapi).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am brand new with android .... but as a general rule 'error suppression' is not a good idea, especially during development

Comment: also ... +1 for the explanation about the `Activity class` ... ... but question: doesn't that effectively mean that the `onCreate` method  (that apparently extends `onCreateView` ) is unusable for API < 11 ?? ... thanks.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd i have added onCreateView for Fragment because there is no onCreate method in Fragment

Answer (score 1):

**Because fragments added in API 11 and your current minSDK = 8**, you can see that [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Your are using AppCompatActivity which calls Fragment class in onCreateView() method, Although your code doesn't implement onCreateView() but AppCompatActivity does. you can read the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#FragmentActivity.onCreateView%28java.lang.String%2Candroid.content.Context%2Candroid.util.AttributeSet%29)

**Solution** there are two possible solution

1- change sdk version in manifest to >= 11

2- (if you use API below 11) use SuppressLint annotation to suppress any error related to sdkVersion and implement onCreateView as follows

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) 
        return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I needed if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)

Answer (score 0):

change your minsdkversion from manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I resolved it by changing the superclass of my activity.
Insted of "public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity",
I typed "public class MainActivity extends Activity".
After the change the issue got resolved.

Comment: Is this the full answer?

Comment: This is getting away from the problem. From extending Activity we have moved on to AppCompatActivity for backward Compatibility of newer features and you are suggesting to leave them altogether and work with the same old Activity calss

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, right click on one of your projects and click properties, select Java Compiler from left list, uncheck "Enable project specific settings", click on Configure Workspace Settings link, change Compiler compliance level to the highest version (for now it's 1.8).
then click OK and accept everything it asked.

Also to make sure, change Project Build Target api of all of your projects to the latest api.

EDIT:
I personally had to uncheck "Enable project specific settings" for all of library projects one by one. changed Compiler compliance level of workspace to 1.8 then checked "Enable project specific settings" only for my own main project and changed its Compiler compliance level to 1.6.