# Call requires API level 11 in v7_appcompat

Tags: android, google-play-services

I see a `Lint` error

> Call requires API level 11 (current min is 9)

for the following files in `v7_appcompat` lib:

```
android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle in notification_media_action.xml
android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle in notification_media_cancel_action.xml    
android:attr/dividerHorizontal in notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml
android:attr/dividerHorizontal in notification_template_big_media.xml
```

What can I do?

Comment: Make the minSDKVersion to 11

Comment: I need to support devices with SDK >= 9.

Comment: Check this related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294607/call-requires-api-level-11current-min-is-9-android-app-activityoncreateview