# Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Activity#onCreateView

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appcompat

Today, i have been updated android support v7 appcompat to version 23. After update, eclipse show error `Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Activity#onCreateView` at header of file. This is my java code

```
package xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xx.activity;

import xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xx.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayout layInfo;
    private TextView lblSongName;
    private TextView lblStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sing);

        layInfo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay_info);
        lblSongName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_song_name);
        lblStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_status);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you extend from `ActionBarActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` has been deprecated

Comment: Check if you are using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, i don't use `onCreateView` any time, above is all of code of activity

Comment: Deprecation of ActionBarActivity is just a `hint` for you to use new AppCompatActivity directly. See what @ChrisBanes himself says about: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29799144/2649012

Comment: I do have the same problem. I think the only chance is currently to upgrade to API 11 - at least I have not found another solution

Comment: It is a very strange issue. You minSdk supports this level. Are you using api23 to compile?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, You are right, it is very strange! `onCreateView` function added from api version 1, but now show me error about min support api 8

Comment: Yes, that is an odd one, it started to happen to me as well somewhat recently every now and then when changing code. I believe that's not an Eclipse error, but a Lint generated one. And it possibly started to occur when updating to Android SDK Build Tools 23.0.0. It appears to go away when cleaning the project .

Comment: @DuHuynh Did you ever manage to solve this problem? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: @grimrader22, that maybe problem of eclipse. My Pc in my company show error but my Pc in my home not show. So i don't know what is exactly of problem...

Comment: everytime i open eclipse, this error show up beside the package. So i just clean the project and it disappear.

Comment: This is caused by a bug in the Android SDK - anyone who's affected should [star it here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188677).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call requires API level 11(current min is 8) android.app.Activity#onCreateView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181705/call-requires-api-level-11current-min-is-8-android-app-activityoncreateview)